# Using Math.Round with a Unit of Measure

Tags: f#, units-of-measurement

I'm trying to use `Math.Round` within a function to round a monetary amount as follows:

```
let calculateTaxablePayToDate previousPayToDate taxablePayThisMonth =
    taxablePayThisMonth
    |> fun (x:decimal) -> Math.Round(x)
    |> fun x -> x + previousPayToDate
```

The types that I'm passing in are both of type `decimal<GBP>`. When I try and run them through the function though I get:

> This expression was expected to have type
>       `decimal`     but here has type
>       `int<GBP>`

How am I able to use `Math.Round` on a figure that has a Unit of Measure attached?

Comment: Please add code snippet that could be compiled with a sample how do  you call `calculateTaxablePayToDate` function. Otherwise it's hard to find out

Comment: Note that you could use `(+) previousPayToDate` instead of `fun x -> x + previousPayToDate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Math.Round` expects a raw value, not a measure value. You can wrap it in a function generic in the measure type:

```
open System
open Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives

let roundMeasure<[<Measure>]'u>(x: decimal<'u>): decimal<'u> = Math.Round(decimal x) |> DecimalWithMeasure
```

you should then be able to do:

```
let calculateTaxablePayToDate previousPayToDate taxablePayThisMonth =
        taxablePayThisMonth |> roundMeasure |> fun x -> x + previousPayToDate
```

or

```
let calculateTaxablePayToDate previousPayToDate taxablePayThisMonth =
    previousPayToDate + (roundMeasure taxablePayThisMonth)
```

Comment: Thanks @Lee. What is the final function that roundMeasure pipes to; `DecimalWithMeasure`? It's not compiling that part at the moment.

Comment: Never mind, I worked it out. Had to open `LanguagePrimitives` :) Thanks

Comment: Of topic, but I think pipelines don't really help here. Why not just `(roundMeasure taxablePayThisMonth) + previous`?

Comment: That works too. Thanks Tomas. How does that syntax work; using the brackets around `roundMeasure` and `taxablePayThisMonth`?

Comment: @Stu1986C it applies the function `roundMeasure` to the value `taxablePayThisMonth`; the parentheses ensure that the function application is evaluated first and the result subsequently passed to the addition operation.